# Continuous surjection from $X(D_n)$ onto $\operatorname{Homeo}_0(D_n)$

Tags: gn.general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, homeomorphism

Let $n>1$ and let $\mathfrak{X}(D_n)$ denote the set of continuous vector fields on the closed disc $D_n\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $\operatorname{Homeo}_0(D_n)$ be the set of homeomorphism of the disc $D_n$ fixing $0$ which are isotopic to the identity.  Equip both these with the compact-open topology.

Is there an explicit surjective continuous map from $\mathfrak{X}(D_n)$ onto $\operatorname{Homeo}_0(D_n)$?

Comment: You're asking for a continuous map with no further assumption? it might exist for some "bad" reason (bad meaning quite unrelated to the context, working with $\mathrm{Homeo}_0(D_n)$ replaced with quite general nonempty connected Polish spaces). (This might be explicit too!)

Comment: I added the word *explicit*.  Otherwise, it goes well with me if it's for some unrelated reason just as long as it can be expressed explicitly.

Comment: But usually these kind of "general type reasons" can also be made explicit. For instance, a continuous surjection $[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ can be made explicit, and one could imagine finding an explicit continuous surjection $X(D_n)\to \mathcal{H}$ ($\mathcal{H}$ separable infinite-dim Hilbert) as well as an explicit continuous surjection $\mathcal{H}\to \mathrm{Homeo}_0(D_n)$.

Comment: The following "one" is straight-forward: $f \to \pi'\circ f\circ \iota$, where $\iota:D_n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the inclusion and ${\pi}$ is the identity on $D_n$ and on $\mathbb{R}^n-D_n$ it sends $x$ to $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$.  However, when I try to incorporate the conditions that the image is a homeomorphism then such a map breaks (likewise with the constraint that the origin must be fixed).

Comment: By the way your title doesn't match your question (homeo vs continuous surjective)

Comment: Thanks.  What space did you have in mind when you described $\mathcal{H}\to Homeo_0(D_n)$?

Comment: This may be related to YCor's comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971161?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents